# An intuitive idea of mapping spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

In the category of pointed simplicial sets, we have an adjunction between smash product and mapping space.

We define mapping space as follows:

$\textbf{Map}_*(X,Y)_n$ := $Hom_{sSets_*}(X \wedge \triangle_{+}^{n} , Y)$

It would be helpful if someone could provide me with some intuition to think about $\textbf{Map}_*(X,Y)$. What is the geometric realization of this?